# Gimp cannot select/move an image but only able to move as layer or grouped images

Tags: gimp

I'm struggling with that I cannot move one image anymore but only am able to move grouped images or as a layer. Here is the screen recording [video](https://yuis.xsrv.jp/images/ss/ShareX_ScreenShot_d9b29b1b-19c3-4d48-b7ac-5775255f856c.mp4). (sorry for the link but couldn't render video file on stackexhange)

Screenshot of artboard

[image: screenshot of artboard]

so, how can I solve this weird issue?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the photos in your document are flattened to 1 layer. You cannot move individual parts of the document because all images in the document are merged together to create 1 image. When you move the layer, you move everything in the layer. If you want to move 1 photo, you need to put it on a separate layer.

Answer (score 0):

Same as the other answer, your photos are all on the same layer.

Now, for a possible root cause: you pasted images, and anchored the floating selection (Ctrl-H), which merges the pasted image into your target layer. Instead you can do either:

- After the paste, use `Layer>To new layer` to create a new layer from the floating selection, instead of anchoring it
- Replace the paste by `Edit>Paste as>New layer` to directly create a new layer
- If you are editing the other images in Gimp, you can just copy the layer from an image to another by dragging it from the Layers list of the source image to the canvas of the target. If you are in single-window mode this is done thus:

  - activate the source image (`SRC` in screenshot)
  - click on the layer in the Layers list
  - drag it to the tab of the target (`TGT` in screenshot)
  - drop it

[image]